# How can I generate a SQL Server database backup programmatically using C# or VB.net with selected table data only

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I need to create a SQL Server database backup programmatically using C#. This database backup should contain entire database configuration.

But main requirement is that in the backup, table data should be related with specific to record ID.

For example, `EmployeeID` is the PK of one of the tables. Same `EmployeeID` is used as FK in some other table. So, I need to create a backup file programmatically with tables that will hold the data only for specific `EmployeeID`.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Why would you need a backup but to filter the data and only store it for one EmployeeID?

Comment: SQL Server can't back up anything but all the data. If you need some data removed, you'll have to remove it yourself first. Back up, restore, throw away data on the restored database, then back up the result.

Comment: Your requirements seem to contradict each other here. A database backup is a backup of the ENTIRE database. If it wasn't, then it isn't a database backup. It seems maybe you are only trying to capture some certain data? If you could expand on what you are really trying to do here we might be able to help.

Comment: **Why? What is the end goal you are trying to accomplish?** A new database with data only for a specific employee (in your example) serves no purpose in its own. What is the actual business requirement you are trying to solve? Based on that information you will probably get some better suggestions or answers on how to proceed.

Comment: A backup is designed to be restored.  This request makes no sense.  Even so, if you want to do it programatically, you'd just delete everything you don't want and then take a backup.  You can't do it outside of the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a solution for every requirement you might have. Your problem also has a solution as follows:

1. Write a SQL script that will create a clone of the Source database on same SQL Server instance.
2. This cloned database should contain the data and fields that you require and data can be specific to Employee Id X. (sample code provided below). This **SELECT statement** will itself **CREATE TABLE SCHEMA** for you based on the source table and will also **INSERT SPECIFIC records** in the destination table based on the **FILTER** you apply in **WHERE** condition.
3. Output of this SQL script should be a “.BAK” file
4. Once backup of the cloned database is generated, your script should immediately delete the cloned database.
5. You need to configure following values in SQL script while deployment

a. Source Database  - A database for which backup has to be created

b. Employee Id – This would be an id of the company for which data    needs to be exported. Default value of this can be X.

c. Backup File path – A path on the server where the database backup    can reside.

```
    USE master
    IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='Test')
    DROP DATABASE Test

    CREATE DATABASE Test


    IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='Test')
    BEGIN

        USE Test

        SELECT * 
        INTO [Destination_Table1] 
        FROM [SourceDatabase].[dbo].[Source_Table1]
        WHERE [SourceDatabase].[dbo].[Source_Table1].[EmployeeID] = 78

        BACKUP DATABASE Test  
        TO DISK = 'D:\SSIS\DB\Test.Bak'
        WITH FORMAT,  
        MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',  
        NAME = 'Test';  

        IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='Test')
        DROP DATABASE Test

    END
```

Do let me know if you need any further help.